# Docker multiple containers everytime I run docker-compose run web

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

Everytime I run `docker-compose run web [rails-command]` it creates another contiainer, is this normal?
Is there a way to not do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is very normal. The containers are short-lived though, existing just for the duration of the command

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `run` spawns a new container at every execution.

If you wanted to run a command inside an existing container you would have to use `exec`, eg:

```
docker-compose exec web [rails-command]
```